# C++ throw() (_NOEXCEPT) after function declaration

Tags: c++, function, throw, noexcept

I have seen in the Visual C++ include file `<vector>` using `throw()` after a function:

```
size_type capacity() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return current length of allocated storage
    return (this->_Myend - this->_Myfirst);
    }
```

With the `_NOEXCEPT` a macro for `throw()`, so the above looks like:

```
size_type capacity() const throw()
    {   // return current length of allocated storage
    return (this->_Myend - this->_Myfirst);
    }
```

But what does the throw do? I have seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055387/throw-keyword-in-functions-signature-c) question why it is a bad practise, but why has it been put there when nothing is thrown or caught?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the benefit to limiting throws allowed by a C++ function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609332/what-is-the-benefit-to-limiting-throws-allowed-by-a-c-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The throw exception specification is deprecated in C++11 and replaced by noexcept.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec:

> noexcept is an improved version of throw(), which is deprecated in
>   C++11. Unlike throw(), noexcept will not call std::unexpected and may
>   or may not unwind the stack, which potentially allows the compiler to
>   implement noexcept without the runtime overhead of throw().